# Global Dedekind zeta function determines local zeta functions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I've read that, given two number fields $K, K'$ with equal [Dedekind zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) $\zeta_K=\zeta_{K'}$ then, for every rational prime $p$, their local zeta functions are equal too, i.e. $\zeta_K^{(p)}=\zeta_{K'}^{(p)}$ where
$$\zeta_K^{(p)}(s)=\prod_{\substack{ Q\in \mathcal{O}_K \\ Q|p }}\frac{1}{1-N(Q)^{-s}}.$$

Is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: Since $N(p) = p^n$ where $n = [K:\mathbb{Q}]$, If $Q|p$ a maximal ideal then $N(Q) = p^{f(Q|p)}$ with $f(Q| p) = [\mathcal{O}_K/Q : \mathbb{F}_p]$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions  so the local zeta is really a polynomial in $p^{-s}$ showing the splitting of $p \mathcal{O}_K$

Answer (score 4):

In general, if a Dirichlet series
$$L(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a(n)n^{-s}$$
has an Euler product
$$L(s) = \prod_p L_p(s),$$ you can determine the local factor $L_p(s)$ by just reading off the coefficients of $L(s)$ at the prime powers:
$$L_p(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a(p^k) p^{-ks}.$$

This is true in particular for Dedekind zeta functions.  Therefore, equal Dedekind zeta functions will have equal coefficents $a(n)$, therefore equal local zeta functions.

Comment: Can you prove this fact or give me a reference? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A good reference is Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Section 11.5, Theorems 11.6 and 11.7, pgs. 230-231.

Comment: Thanks. An other question before I can accept your answer: you are assuming that $L_p(s)=\zeta_K^{(p)}(s)$, why is it true?

Comment: You can take that to be the definition of $L_p(s)$ in the context of Dedekind zeta functions.